# Let $A$ be the set of elements of $[0,1]$ whose base $m$ expansion has no finite sequence $a_1a_2a_3..a_n$, does $A$ have $0$ measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be the set of elements of $[0,1]$ whose base $m$ expansion has no finite sequence $a_1a_2a_3..a_n$, does $A$ have $0$ measure?

I think so. For example the cantor set is the set of elements of $[0,1]$ that do not have a $1$ in its base 3 expansion. I think the argument that shows the cantor set has measure $0$ can  be adapted for any case but I am having trouble generalizing it.

Any references or help would be appriciated.

Comment: This is a simple consequence of Borel's "Normal numbers" theorem; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number .It follows from the "second Borel-Cantelli lemma", and for that matter, from the strong law of large numbers.

Comment: As written $A$ has full measure and its complement, which is the countably infinite set of elements that do have a finite representation is of measure zero.  Did you mean the reverse?

Comment: @RossMillikan I mean $x \in A \iff$ when you expand $x$ in base $m$ you never encounter the sequence $a_1a_2a_3...a_n$.

Comment: Some of the questions listed under "Related" on this page may help you to answer your question, 2132123

Comment: Then @kimchilover's comment applies nicely.

Comment: So have you looked at the Related questions, 2132123?

Comment: Are you still here, 2132123?